# Trying to build mysql-connector-cpp on Windows

Tags: c++, mysql-connector

I want to be able to build mysql-connector/c++ applications in debug mode (VS2k17), and understand the only way I can do that is to first build `mysql-connector-cpp` from source on my computer (Windows 10/64bit). I tried the following:

`cmake . -DWITH_SSL=C:\Users\Rawb\source\libraries\OpenSSL-Win64`

and it looks to complete successfully ...

```
Install location: C:/Users/Rawb/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 8.0
Connector libraries will be installed at: lib
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/Rawb/source/repos/mcc2/mysql-connector-cpp
```

but when I run the following cmake build ...

`cmake --build . --config`

it fails with this output ...

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'ssleay32.lib' [C:\Users\Rawb\source\repos\mcc2\mysql-connector-cpp\connector.vcxproj]
Done Building Project "C:\Users\Rawb\source\repos\mcc2\mysql-connector-cpp\connector.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
Done Building Project "C:\Users\Rawb\source\repos\mcc2\mysql-connector-cpp\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
Build FAILED.

"C:\Users\Rawb\source\repos\mcc2\mysql-connector-cpp\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\Rawb\source\repos\mcc2\mysql-connector-cpp\connector.vcxproj" (default target) (10) ->
(Link target) ->
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'ssleay32.lib' [C:\Users\Rawb\source\repos\mcc2\mysql-connector-cpp\connector.vcxproj]
0 Warning(s)
1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:14.57
```

What might I be doing wrong? Do I just need to place the `ssleay32.lib` file somewhere? I do have a copy of it but not sure how it should be included. Or is it more complex? I.e. Do I need to build Open SSL first on my machine as well? This is a deep rabbit hole for me, I may be in over my head haha!

NOTE: I also asked this question on reddit with no luck, so hoping someone here might know.

Comment: _"I want to be able to build mysql-connector/c++ applications in debug mode (VS2k17), and understand the only way I can do that is to first build mysql-connector-cpp from source on my computer "_ Is that true? Perhaps there's a Visual Studio oddity at play but, from working with this library on Linux, it is not true. I doubt it's true on Windows, either: having to rebuild every 3rd party dependency in debug to get a debug build of your own code would be completely prohibitive. If it is true please expand on how and why that is.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - According to the documentation, yes, _"When linking dynamically, it is possible to build your code in debug mode even if the connector libraries are built in release mode. However, in that case, it will not be possible to step inside connector code during a debug session. To be able to do that, or to build in debug mode while linking statically to the connector, you must build Connector/C++ from source yourself using the Debug configuration."_(https://downloads.mysql.com/docs/connector-cpp-1.1-en.a4.pdf)

Comment: Okay, so that says you _don't_ need to do this, unless you want to step into the connector code. Why do you want to step into the connector code?

Comment: Thanks for bringing that to my attention, I wasn't readying it that way, I was thinking I couldn't 'step in' to debug at all. What really confused me is that any time I previously tried setting the active build to debug, and running the Local Windows Debugger, the program would just crash immediately (but ran fine as release). I just tried building now and it seems to work - so clearly I had some misconfig issue or something else in debug / separate from this issue in my OP. I'll mark this resolved. Thanks!

Comment: It's just saying you have to build the library in debug if you want to debug the library. But you don't want to debug the library (unless you're developing it!). The one part I don't quite grok is the part about static linking. Hopefully you're not doing that and therefore we don't have to dig into it ;)

Comment: I'm just a novice/hobby programmer and with c++, but right now I believe I am using the dynamic linking (mysqlcppconn.lib in my compiler's linker). Is that what I should be doing? Thanks again. PS - no, I'm not interested in developing mysql-connector itself :) At least not yet anyways haha

Comment: Yes that's fine.

Comment: It's still crashing on me, so it must be another issue .. I have another question to ask when StackOverflow lets me in ~60 mins :)

Comment: Just posted this, man im stumped! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54858015/bulding-mysql-connector-c-application-in-debug-on-windows-vs2k17

Comment: Just a heads up - that's going to be closed without a [MCVE]

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I just added a link to the simple source, will that suffice?

Comment: No, it needs to be in the question. Do follow the link I gave you. Content-wise though that's good

Comment: Oh, looks like you just deleted it. Was going to take a look. Ah well, cheers

Comment: OK, I've deleted the post for now, until I get it sorted. I'm actually pretty drained - enough for tonight anyways - I've been trying to build mysql-connector-cpp in debug mode for a very long time and keep setting it aside, but want to get it resolved properly. It's been a tough mountain to climb for a hobby programmer like me! I will return tomorrow maybe :) Thanks for all your help.

Comment: I un-deleted if you do want to have a peak. I may sign-off shortly for the night, but I don't mind if mods delete it until I can fix it up. I'm just stumped, it seems no matter what include+lib i use (from various versions of downloading mysql-connector-c++) it either throws the `ordinal` error, or begins walking through the program and crashes with a bad allocation memory error, or exception mentioned in the new post. Thanks,

Comment: Q: Did you read my post?  Did it help.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you're using MSVS (any version, including MSVS 2017), then I'd suggest using "NMake" (instead of cmake).  Or just create a new C/C++ library project in the MSVS IDE.
2. The flag you're looking for is `/LIBPATH`.  I don't think you need "-D", but you *certainly* need "/LIBPATH".

   Here are the MSVS linker options:

   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-options?view=vs-2017
3. Finally, you *might* be able to do all the troubleshooting/tracing you want *without* actually debugging (and rebuilding) the connector code.

   Here's how to enable tracing in the MySQL Connector:

   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/1.1/en/connector-cpp-debug-tracing.html

Please let me know if this helps.