# Bulding mysql-connector c++ application in debug on Windows, VS2K17

Tags: c++, mysql-connector

I'm trying to run a simple `mysql-connector` (c++) application in debug mode, but it seems to fail when it gets to the following line (see full source below):

`pstmt = con->prepareStatement(query);`

and using the Local Windows Debugger in Visual Studio, it stops [at that line above] with this Exception Unhandled:

`Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFD7921A388 in Database.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x0000004F7E8FC920.`

This same application runs fine if I set my active build configuration to `Release` (VS 2017, Win10/64bit). I'm using mysql-connector-c++-noinstall-1.1.12

While in debug for the Active build configuration, if I just hit ctrl+f5 (build without debugging) I get an alert/pop-up:

`Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library
Program: ..\Database.exe
abort() has been called
(Press Retry to debug the application)`

Any idea what I might be doing wrong here? At first I thought it was related to not building mysql-connector myself (per my previous post here: [Trying to build mysql-connector-cpp on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54857347/trying-to-build-mysql-connector-cpp-on-windows?noredirect=1#comment96486369_54857347)).

EDIT: I tried using two different downloads of `mysql-connector-c++`:

1. `mysql-connector-c++-noinstall-1.1.12-winx64`
2. `Connector C++ 8.0`

And they produce the following error/crash windows respectively:

1. `The ordinal 4699 could not be located in the dynamic link library c:\users\..\Database\x64\Debug\mysqlcppconn.dll`
2. `The ordinal 4699 could not be located in the dynamic link library c:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\mysqlcppconn-7-vs14.dll`

Thanks again!

---

Full source: https://pastebin.com/GmsNEEFa

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to build mysql-connector-cpp on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54857347/trying-to-build-mysql-connector-cpp-on-windows)

Comment: Does the function work with a C++ string? Or does it need a C type string?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your previous post:

You *should* be able to build OK; the specific error indicated your link command was failing to find the SSL library, which you indicated you had on your system.  My suggestion was to use nmake or create an MSVS project (there's nothing "wrong" with cmake ... but if you're going to use Microsoft's compiler, it's generally just much easier to use Microsoft's tools) and - most importantly - to use the correct "link path" syntax.

Regarding your current post:

1. Q: Did you install the MySQL Connector, following the instructions in [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/8.0/en/connector-cpp-installation-binary.html#connector-cpp-installation-binary-windows)?
2. My previous suggestion still holds: if you have MSVS, then go into the IDE, create an MSVS C++ console-mode project, and cut/paste the code you posted to Pastebin into your new project.  **CREATE AN MSVS PROJECT**.
3. Go into MSVS > Project > Properties and add a) the path to your MySQL includes, and b) the path to your MySql libraries.
4. Add the MySql *dynamic* library (LIB/vs14/mysqlcppconn8.lib) to your link command.  Follow the instructions [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/8.0/en/connector-cpp-apps-windows-visual-studio.html).
5. Post back what you find. It *should* work.  Please specify *exactly* what you did, and copy/paste the *exact* error message if it doesn't.
6. Once things are working ... then create your "actual" build scripts however you want.  At least you'll have a good "reference" to fall back on.

'Hope that helps!

PS:

The binary .msi has *two* C/C++ connector libraries: a static library, and a dynamic .dll.  You link to *either* one with a ".lib" file: "LIB/vs14/mysqlcppconn8.lib" for the .dll, or "LIB/vs14/mysqlcppconn8-static.lib" for the static library.

Comment: thanks so much for your assistance. I created a fresh MSVS console project, added the required MySQL include folder, Boost folder, and linked the mysqlcppconn8.lib dynamic library as well. Using the code in my 'Full source' pastebin above, I'm unfortunately getting a number of errors -  after I build in Debug, x64. I'm new to Stack Overflow so I'm not sure how best to share the errors... but here's a pastebin for now: https://pastebin.com/hBUkNwKw - Thanks again!

Comment: OK - progress.  These are all link-time errors (e.g. `Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl sql::SQLString::~SQLString(void)" (__imp_??1SQLString@sql@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function main`).  This means that the linker isn't finding the MySql connectyor references it needs as it tries to build your .exe. Because the project is somehow "messed up": it's either picking up the wrong headers, it's not finding or picking up the wrong .lib, or both.

Comment: Does that mean I'm still missing something for the linker? Or perhaps the version of MySQL and Mysql Connector I'm using are conflicting? I've tried various combinations of both (i.e. MySQL Server 5.7 and 8.0, and MySQL connector 8.0.12 and 8.0.15). Thanks again for your efforts -

Comment: An update to my last comment, and an important clarification:the ability to build at all and the version used in my original post was Mysql connector ++ 1.1.12 (I'm able to build in release / runs fine, but debug dies at the `Exception Unhandled` mentioned). I haven't been able to get any 8.0.x to work in debug or release. I hope this clarifies. Thanks in advance if any ideas how to diz my issue.